# C++: Thread synchronization scenario on Linux Platform

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, synchronization

I am implementing multithreaded C++ program for Linux platform where I need a functionality similar to WaitForMultipleObjects().

While searching for the solution I observed that there are articles that describe how to achieve WaitForMultipleObjects() functionality in Linux with examples but those examples does not satisfy the scenario that I have to support.

The scenario in my case is pretty simple. I have a daemon process in which the main thread exposes a method/callback to the outside world for example to a DLL. The code of the DLL is not under my control. The same main thread creates a new thread "Thread 1". Thread 1 has to execute kind of an infinite loop in which it would wait for a shutdown event (daemon shutdown) OR it would wait on the data available event being signaled through the exposed method/callback mentioned above.

In short the thread would be waiting on shutdown event and data available event where if shutdown event is signaled the wait would satisfy and the loop would be broken or if data available event is signaled then also wait would satisfy and thread would do business processing.

In windows, it seems very straight forward. Below is the MS Windows based pseudo code for my scenario.

```
//**Main thread**

//Load the DLL
LoadLibrary("some DLL")

//Create a new thread
hThread1 = __beginthreadex(..., &ThreadProc, ...)

//callback in main thread (mentioned in above description) which would be called by the     DLL
void Callbackfunc(data)
{
    qdata.push(data);
    SetEvent(s_hDataAvailableEvent);
}

void OnShutdown()
{
    SetEvent(g_hShutdownEvent);
    WaitforSingleObject(hThread1,..., INFINITE);
    //Cleanup here
}

//**Thread 1**

unsigned int WINAPI ThreadProc(void *pObject)
{
    while (true)
    {

        HANDLE hEvents[2];
        hEvents[0] = g_hShutdownEvent;
        hEvents[1] = s_hDataAvailableEvent;

        //3rd parameter is set to FALSE that means the wait should satisfy if state of  any one of the objects is signaled.
        dwEvent = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, hEvents, FALSE, INFINITE);
        switch (dwEvent) 
        {   
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0: 
            // Shutdown event is set, break the loop
            return 0;   

            case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:
            //do business processing here
            break; 

            default: 
            // error handling
        }
    }
}
```

I want to implement the same for Linux. According to my understanding when it would come to Linux, it has totally different mechanism where we need to register for signals. If the termination signal arrives, the process would come to know that it is about to shutdown but before that it is necessary for the process to wait for the running thread to gracefully shutdown.

Comment: The POSIX equivalent to WFMO is `select`/`poll`/`epoll`.  Almost everything in Linux is a waitable file descriptor, and you can always make some pipes to act as waitable interthread events.  So then your signal handler would just write to a pipe connected to the other thread, which would be woken.  You can even use a datagram socket or datagram FIFO as your thread-safe queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this in Linux would be using condition variables.  While this is not the same as `WaitForMultipleObjects` in Windows, you will get the same functionality.

Use two `bool`s to determine whether there is data available or a shutdown must occur.
Then have the shutdown function and the data function both set the bools accordingly, and signal the condition variable.

```
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_t hThread1; // this isn't a good name for it in linux, you'd be 
                    // better with something line "tid1" but for 
                    // comparison's sake, I've kept this

bool shutdown_signalled;
bool data_available;

void OnShutdown()
{
    //...shutdown behavior...
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    shutdown_signalled = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
}

void Callbackfunc(...)
{
    // ... whatever needs to be done ...
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    data_available = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
}


void *ThreadProc(void *args)
{
    while(true){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while (!(shutdown_signalled || data_available)){
            // wait as long as there is no data available and a shutdown
            // has not beeen signalled
            pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mutex);
        }
        if (data_available){
            //process data
            data_available = false;
        }
        if (shutdown_signalled){
            //do the shutdown
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
            return NULL;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex); //you might be able to put the unlock
        // before the ifs, idk the particulars of your code
    }
}
int main(void)
{
    shutdown_signalled = false;
    data_available = false;
    pthread_create(&hThread1, &ThreadProc, ...);
    pthread_join(hThread1, NULL);
    //...
}
```

I know windows has condition variables as well, so this shouldn't look too alien.  I don't know what rules windows has about them, but on a POSIX platform the `wait` needs to be inside of a `while` loop because "spurious wakeups" can occur.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to write unix or linux specific code, you have differenr APIs available:

- pthread: provides threads, mutex, condition variables
- IPC (inter process comunication) mechanisms : mutex, semaphore, shared memory
- signals

For threads, the first library is mandatory (there are lower level syscalls on linux, but it's more tedious). For events, the three may be used.

The system shutdown event generate termination (SIG_TERM) and kill (SIG_KILL) signals broadcasted to all the relevant processes. Hence an individual daemon shutdown can also be initiated this way. The goal of the game is to catch the signals, and initiate process shutdown. The important points are:

- the signal mechanism is made in such a way that it is not necessary to wait for them

  Simply install a so called handler using `sigaction`, and the system will do the rest.
- the signal is set to the process, and *any* thread may intercept it (the handler may execute in any context)

  You need therefore to install a signal handler (see [sigaction(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction)), and somehow pass the information to the other threads that the application must terminate.

The most convenient way is probably to have a global mutex protected flag which all your threads will consult regularily. The signal handler will set that flag to indicate shutdown. For the worker thread, it means

- telling the remote host that the server is closing down,
- close its socket on read
- process all the remaining received commands/data and send answers
- close the socket
- exit

For the main thread, this will mean initiating a join on the worker thread, then exit.

This model should not interfer with the way data is normally processed: a blocking call to `select` or `poll` will return the error `EINTR` if a signal was caught, and for a non blocking call, the thread is regularily checking the flag, so it does work too.